# MaterializeCSS: pushed element overflowing row instead of breaking to next line

Tags: css, materialize

I'm using Materialize's grid system, where I have a `Row` with dozens of `l3` columns. It works as expected and it displays 4 cols per line.

Now I want to be able to enlarge a column on click (making it `l9`). I already succeded in toggling the l3/l9 class on click, but I'm having issues with the push / pull functionality.

If the clicked column is in the 3rd or 4th position, I want to pull it by 3 or 6 respectively, so it stays on the same line. 
At the same time, I'm pushing the columns that come before it by 9, and I expected them to break to the next line accordingly.

The problem is: instead of breaking to the next line they are overflowing the row, totally breaking the design.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Not really a lot to go off of and not sure if I'm right, but maybe you can do something like this:

```
    $('.row.l3').on('click',function(){
    if($(this).index() <= 1){
        ... Toggle push
    }else{
        ... Toggle pull
    }
})
```

Also, remember that you should only have a total of 12 col(for example: l3+l3+l3+l3) in each row.

Good luck solving your problem =)